# Tips to setup a high performance software testing lab?

Tags: test-design, test-tools

Every field people set up some kind of the labs like developer setup some developers lab, Penetration tester setup penetration testing lab with the different environment so I want the tips to set up a high-performance software testing lab.

Comment: define details. What software, what performance. What you found so far, so we don't have to mention the basics.

Comment: What _actual_ problem do you want to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Full-controlled, Scalable, and Isolated are my key.

For high-performance testing (in case of throughput or load test), reaching the maximum capacity or break-out point of the software is main goal. Sometimes the bottleneck is not your focus software, but it's other component or even network.

Therefore you need **Full-controlled & Scalable** environment that allow you to tune any component in your system, or network. Add more machine, or more resources. Sometimes you might need to remove some resources but still similar to your customer actual environment to achieve the test with valid and stable result.

Since high-performance testing is sensitive, any network traffic or cpu/memory consumption from any other application can make a huge effect to the test result. Then you also need **isolated** environment which this kind of issue may be minimize.

Hope it helps. Have fun and enjoy your test.

Answer (score 0):

Since the software industry is expanding at a very fast pace, establishing a software testing lab needs you to focus on so many different things. To mention a few, I would like to include:

- A team of enthusiastic and passionate QA testers who have all the knowledge and will to outperform.
- The right set of tools and technology stack that could help you to drive proficiency to your lab
- A perfect understanding of balancing manual and automation testing
- A proper device setup or technology that could help you create QA solutions for the masses.